# Google app engine: object has no attribute ToMessage

Tags: python-2.7, google-app-engine, google-cloud-endpoints

I am trying to implement a service which checks if the logged in user is on a datastore, if yes returns True, if not returns False.
Here is the code I am using:

```
import endpoints

from google.appengine.ext import ndb
from protorpc import remote
from protorpc import messages

from endpoints_proto_datastore.ndb import EndpointsModel
from google.appengine.api import users

class AuthRes(messages.Message):
    message = messages.StringField(1)

class UserModel(EndpointsModel):
    user = ndb.UserProperty()

@endpoints.api(name='myapi', version='v1', description='My Little API')
class MyApi(remote.Service):

    @UserModel.method(path='myuser', http_method='GET', name='myuser.check')
    def UserCheck(self, cls):
        user = users.get_current_user()
        if user:
            myuser = cls.query().filter(cls.user.user_id() == user.user_id()).get()
            if not myuser:
                  return AuthRes(message="False")
            else:
                  return AuthRes(message="True")
        else:
            return AuthRes(message="False")


application = endpoints.api_server([MyApi], restricted=False)
```

I always get `'AuthRes' object has no attribute 'ToMessage'`

Comment: What lines is generating the error? Can you post a stack trace?

Comment: the return statement is the one returning the error

Comment: @TarikMokafih could you post the full traceback?

Answer (score 0):

I believe instead of this:

```
@UserModel.method(path='myuser', http_method='GET', name='myuser.check')
```

you want this:

```
from protorpc import message_types  # add at the top

@endpoints.method(message_types.VoidMessage, AuthRes, path='myuser', http_method='GET', name='myuser.check')
```